# Expansion of $(1+z+x)^{2n}$

Tags: taylor-expansion

I know that $(1+x)^n$ can be expanded as $1+nx$ for small $x$. Can we also say the same thing for $(1+z+x)^{2n}$ for small $x$, however $z$ is could be a large number. So my question is basically

$$(1+z+x)^{2n} = 1+z+2nx$$ ?

Some variable info:
$z>0$ real number

$n=-0.9$ or $n=-1.7$.

$x$ is a small number.

Comment: For small $x$ is is close to $$(1+z)^{2n}+2nx(1+z)^{2n-1}.$$ And what is 'small' depends heavily on the size of $1+z$ and $n.$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Well z is positive real number and n is around -1 and -2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $z$ is sufficiently away from $-1$ so that $\frac{x}{1+z}$ is small,

$$(1+z+x)^{2n} = (1+z)^{2n} \left(1 + \frac{x}{1+z} \right)^{2n} \approx (1+z)^{2n} \left( 1 + \frac{2nx}{1+z} \right) = (1+z)^{2n} +2nx (1+z)^{2n-1}$$

Comment: well $z$ is a positive real number. So does it work for that case..

Comment: If $z$ is positive then $z$ is sufficiently away from $-1,$ yes. @Neptune

Comment: One last question. Then $(1+z-x)^{2n}  = (1+z)^{2n} -2nx (1+z)^{2n-1}$ ?

Comment: @Neptune Sure, $x$ is small $\iff$ $-x$ is small.